# Queens Domination

Tags: prolog, n-queens

Queen Domination
Given an n×n board, the domination number is the minimum number of queens (or other pieces) needed to attack or occupy every square. For n=8 the queen's domination number is 5.
write a predicate slution(N),to get the minimum number of queens needed to cover all squares.

Comment: N Queens problem is different: find a placement where queens don't attack each other.

Comment: Definitely, my question is : given an n×n board, find the domination number which is the minimum number of queens needed to attack or occupy every square. For n=8 the queen's domination number is 5.

Comment: Hi, CapelliC,the code above are your answer in another questions. Could you give some hints about my problem? I have saw some algorithms, but I still have no idea how to solve the Queens Domination problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is a dumb 'all solutions' snippet:

```
queens_coverage(N, Places) :-
    findall(X/Y, (between(1,N,X), between(1,N,Y)), B),
    placement(B, [], Places).

placement([], Placement, Placement).
placement(Unplaced, SoFar, Placement) :-
    select(Place, Unplaced, Places),
    remove_attacks(Place, Places, Remains),
    placement(Remains, [Place|SoFar], Placement).

remove_attacks(X/Y, [U/V|Places], Remains) :-
    ( U == X ; V == Y ; abs(U-X) =:= abs(V-Y) ),
    !, remove_attacks(X/Y, Places, Remains).
remove_attacks(P, [A|Places], [A|Remains]) :-
    remove_attacks(P, Places, Remains).
remove_attacks(_, [], []).
```

As usual in permutation problems, that code is hopeless inefficient:

```
?- setof(L-Ps, (queens_coverage(4,Ps),length(Ps,L)), R), length(R, T).
R = [3-[1/1, 2/3, 4/2], 3-[1/1, 2/4, 3/2], 3-[1/1, 2/4, 4/3], 3-[1/1, 3/2, 2/4], 3-[1/1, 3/4, ... / ...], 3-[1/1, ... / ...|...], 3-[... / ...|...], 3-[...|...], ... - ...|...],
T = 144.

?- setof(L-Ps, (queens_coverage(5,Ps),length(Ps,L)), R), length(R, T).
R = [3-[1/1, 2/4, 4/3], 3-[1/1, 3/4, 4/2], 3-[1/1, 3/4, 5/3], 3-[1/1, 3/5, 4/3], 3-[1/1, 4/2, ... / ...], 3-[1/1, ... / ...|...], 3-[... / ...|...], 3-[...|...], ... - ...|...],
T = 2064.

?- setof(L-Ps, (queens_coverage(6,Ps),length(Ps,L)), R), length(R, T).
R = [4-[1/1, 2/3, 3/6, 6/2], 4-[1/1, 2/3, 6/2, 3/6], 4-[1/1, 2/4, 4/5, 5/2], 4-[1/1, 2/4, 4/5, ... / ...], 4-[1/1, 2/4, ... / ...|...], 4-[1/1, ... / ...|...], 4-[... / ...|...], 4-[...|...], ... - ...|...],
T = 32640.

?- setof(L-Ps, (queens_coverage(7,Ps),length(Ps,L)), R), length(R, T).
ERROR: Out of global stack
```

Of course, storing all lists is a real waste.

```
?- integrate(min, qc(7), R).
R = 4-[1/2, 2/6, 4/1, 5/5] .

?- integrate(min, qc(8), R).
R = 5-[1/1, 2/3, 3/5, 4/2, 5/4]
```

instead of select/3 you should apply an appropriate heuristic. An easy one could be greedy selection...

*edit*

here is integrate:

```
integrate(min, Goal, R) :-
    State = (_, _),
    repeat,
    (   call(Goal, V),
        arg(1, State, C),
        ( ( var(C) ; V @< C ) -> U = V ; U = C ),
        nb_setarg(1, State, U),
        fail
    ;   arg(1, State, R)
    ),
    !.
```

nb_setarg/3 is a SWI-Prolog builtin, arg/3 an ISO. If your Prolog miss them, you should replace - for instance - with assert/retract.

Integrate takes a predicate, and call it with the additional argument to be compared with the stored current minimum: here it is:

```
qc(N, L-Ps) :- queens_coverage(N,Ps),length(Ps,L).
```

as for the greedy heuristic, the second clause of placement could be replaced by

```
placement(Unplaced, SoFar, Placement) :-
    integrate(min, peek_place_of_min_remain(Unplaced), (_Count,Place,Remains)),
    !, placement(Remains, [Place|SoFar], Placement).

peek_place_of_min_remain(Unplaced, (Count,Place,Remains)) :-
    select(Place, Unplaced, Places),
    remove_attacks(Place, Places, Remains),
    length(Remains, Count).
```

Comment: Hi CapelliC,
1. I need to clarify my problem that: any two queens are allowed to attack each other, that is two queens can be on the same row, colum or diagonal.
But in your provided solution, it seems that two queens cannot be. I want to change the code a little accordingly. Could you explain the below clause really do: 
    remove_attacks(P, [A|Places], [A|Remains]) :-
    remove_attacks(P, Places, Remains). 
I am a little confused. Now I get stuck again.

Comment: 2. Your suggestion is right that I should use a greedy heuristic. I figured out a heuristic but I don't konw how to implement in prolog. The heuristic 
function is h = #(uncovered square). Specifically, every time we choose such square to place the queen that once placing the queen on the square, the number of the remainning uncovered squares is least. 

3. Could you provide the code for the predicate 'integrate' in the command '- integrate(min, qc(7), R).'

Comment: Now I got the detail of 'integrate'. And waiting for more guidance.

Comment: I saw it. Now I need to understand the code thoroughly. So nice!

Comment: 4 ?- qc(8,L).
ERROR: integrate/3: Undefined procedure: peek_place_of_min_remain/3
ERROR:   However, there are definitions for:
ERROR:         peek_place_of_min_remain/2.

Comment: The problem seems to happen in the below code "integrate(min, peek_place_of_min_remain(Unplaced), (_Count,Place,Remains))". The predicate peek_place_of_min_remain has only one parameter, but it is defined to have two parameters in "peek_place_of_min_remain(Unplaced, (Count,Place,Remains))". And also the third parameter for the predicate integrate seems not correct. Hope you could correct it. Thanks again.

Comment: integrate adds a parameter to the predicate argument, where it does `call(Goal, V)`. Seems correct to me - and it's working here, of course.